# Adding a custom filter to Woocommerce using Divi's WooCommerce Product module

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, divi

This is my first time working with wp_query. Was wondering if I'm going about this correctly. I'm creating a custom filter for a WordPress website that uses WooCommerce. I've created a basic form that gets some basic location info and passes it, along with the search distance, in the query string. I'm using the divi page builder for the site and have a WooCommerce Products module on the page that shows the search results.

I've created the below function (I've cleaned out a bunch of junk to make it easier to read). The function works for the most part, except it doesn't refresh the results on the screen. I've checed the SQL fromt the Query using echo $query->request;  and then pasted it into a query window on the database and confirmed that the query is returing results. I've also tried both hooks at the bottom of the function.

I know the function is executing as I can go as far as printing the list of filtered product ids to the page. The only missing piece is getting the Divi WooCommerce Products module to show only the filtered results (it just returns all results)

What am I missing to update the actual results shown on my shop page?

```
function add_filter_to_product_search($query) { 
if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ){
    return;
 }

global $wpdb;

$distance = isset($_GET['distance']) ? intval($_GET['distance']) : 0;


if ($distance > 0) {
    $lat = isset($_GET['lat']) ? floatval($_GET['lat']) : 0; 
    $lng = isset($_GET['lng']) ? floatval($_GET['lng']) : 0; 

    $coords = get_coords($lat, $lng, $distance);
    
          
           if ($lat != 0 && $lng != 0) {
               
               
               $query = new WP_Query([
                'post_type' => 'product',
                   'posts_per_page' => 21,
                'meta_query' => [
                 'relation' => 'AND',
                      [
                    'key' => 'latitude',
                     'type' => 'DECIMAL',
                    'value' => [ $coords[1] , $coords[0]],
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                        ],
                 [
                    'key' => 'longitude',
                     'type' => 'DECIMAL',
                    'value' => [ $coords[2] , $coords[3]],
                    'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
      
                 ]
                             ]
                     ]);
               
                       
                   
         wp_reset_postdata();
               
                    
        return $query ;
        }
   }
}

//add_action('pre_get_posts', 'add_filter_to_product_search');

add_action('woocommerce_product_query', 'add_filter_to_product_search');
```

I've tried returning the query, returning the product list and different hooks to see if I can get it to update.

Comment: Welcome! The hard part is how Divi handles the `wp_query`. I've found Divi "feed" (post, page, etc) modules almost impossible to filter. What I would try, is use `pre_get_posts()` - like `add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', static function( $query) { echo '<pre>' . print_r($query, TRUE) . '</pre>'; return $query; });` This will help identify all the queries run on the page and you can determine what query Divi is actually using to output the products. From there, you can use `pre_get_posts` to filter that using an `if` statement based on a value in the query. Good luck! Divi can be challenging.

Comment: Thanks - that helped as I found that  meta_query wasn't getting populated. I went in and made some changes to set it and now it's showing the meta query, but the results aren't being filtered. It's funny because the Tax query is executing fine. We're using the Yith Ajax filter plug-in, so I wonder if that might be interfering.

Comment: Looking at your code again, I would get rid of the `wp_reset_postdata();` since you're operating in a filter **and** you are resetting the query before it gets to the current return - I would also move the `return $query` outside of your outermost `if ($distance > 0) {`. If that condition isn't met, nothing would return. Things to test!